# An antonym for "sad"?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, adjectives, antonyms

It's common to say: "Isn't it so 'sad' that such and such happened."

Implying that the event in question induces a feeling of sadness.

Is there an antonym for this use of 'sad'?

"Isn't it 'uplifting' that such and such happened." Is the closest word I could think of, but it feels too weak to be a full antonym.

Comment: You want to **look on the bright side**?

Comment: Well, obviously you want to use "gay".  (Not!!)

Comment: Fortunate, touching.. *Sad* is also a synonym of *uplifting*

Comment: By the way, have you tried typing "antonym sad" in Google?????

Comment: @NVZ -- ??? Synonym ???

Comment: @HotLicks In a sense, yes. http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english-thesaurus/uplifting

Comment: @NVZ - An odd definition of "uplifting".

Comment: @Jim Unfortunately, if we simply say what "most people say", anything we do say is unlikely ever to be noticed, let alone change the world!

Comment: I looked up the synonyms of *joyous* and got: *cheerful, ecstatic, exuberant, festive, heartwarming, joyful, jubilant, merry, upbeat, blessed, blithe, delightful, wonderful, glad, gleeful, jocular, jolly, mirthful, pleased, spirited, vigorous...* Take your pick.

Comment: @WS2- Hmm.  OP says, 'it's ***common*** to say *Isn't it so sad*' not 'It's breaking new ground to say *Isn't it crepungelous*..."

Comment: @Jim It really is new ground too. A Google search reveals absolutely nothing. That must be a first! Congratulations!

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it **incredible** that this happened?
Isn't it **awesome** that this happened?
Isn't it **fantastic** that this happened?

I think what you're looking for is almost an implied emotion that can be expressed in words.  Maybe a word that 'shows' happiness like the statements I have shown above.

Answer (score 1):

[***Fortunate***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Fortunate):

Defintion & Example:

> Bringing something good and unforeseen; auspicious.
>
> Yes, life had changed in the last six months, but they were fortunate that those changes had been for the good.

Answer (score -1):

Try **beatifying**

[MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/beatify)

> to make supremely happy

It was *beatifying*.